# Using backreferences for regular expressions in Python LXML with XPath

Tags: python, regex, xml, xpath, lxml

I have to process XML documents with structures like the following:

```
<tok xpos="ABCDE">node1</tok> <tok xpos="XYZ">node2</tok>
<tok xpos="ABCDE">node6</tok> <tok xpos="RST">node7</tok>
<tok xpos="ABTSV">node8</tok> <tok xpos="XYU">node9</tok>
<tok xpos="ABTSV">node14</tok> <tok xpos="XBZ">node15</tok>
```

I need to change part of the value for the attribute 'xpos' just in case the value for the same attribute in the following element starts with a specific sequence of characters. So, in this example, I would need to replace the first two characters of the value for any 'xpos' attribute starting with 'AB' with a new value that will replace 'AB' with 'XX' and will preserve the rest of the characters in the string just in case a specific condition is met. This condition being that the value of the 'xpos' attribute in the following element starts with the sequence of characters 'XY'.

So, after processing, the output would have to be:

```
<tok xpos="XXCDE">node1</tok> <tok xpos="XYZ">node2</tok> 
<tok xpos="ABCDE">node6</tok> <tok xpos="RST">node7</tok>
<tok xpos="XXTSV">node8</tok> <tok xpos="XYU">node9</tok>
<tok xpos="ABTSV">node14</tok> <tok xpos="XBZ">node15</tok>
```

I have tried to do this with the following code. You will notice that I have attempted to use backreferencing by using parentheses for the two substrings in which I divide the values of the affected attributes and then referencing the second capturing group with \2.

```
source = """
<root>
    <tok xpos="ABCDE">node1</tok> <tok xpos="XYZ">node2</tok>
    <tok xpos="ABCDE">node6</tok> <tok xpos="RST">node7</tok>
    <tok xpos="ABTSV">node8</tok> <tok xpos="XYU">node9</tok>
    <tok xpos="ABTSV">node14</tok> <tok xpos="XBZ">node15</tok>
</root>
"""

import lxml.etree

root_element = lxml.etree.XML(source)

for el in root_element.xpath('//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "XY")]/preceding-sibling::tok[1][re:match(@xpos, "^(AB)([A-Z]+)")]', 
        namespaces={"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"}):
        el.set('xpos', 'XX\2')
```

This does not work. I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters
```

How do I go about achieving this goal? In principle, according to this https://www.regular-expressions.info/xpath.html XPath supports backreferences and capturing groups. I just don't know how I should go about implementing it. What am I doing wrong?

JM

Comment: [lxml supports Xpath 1.0](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html). Regex is for Xpath 2.0

Comment: Thanks @LMC. But I can use regex now without any problem. It is just backreferences that give me problems. Other kinds of pattern matching using regular expressions are possible.

Comment: [Code samples](/help/mcve) should be minimal, *complete* and representative. Please look over the [help], especially the "[ask]" article.

Comment: Sorry outis but I thought I had more or less followed the guidelines and that the code samples would be enough to give an idea about the problem. So that I can do it better next time, what would you have added or done differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note python's `lxml` supports regexes through python's implementation, which is different from the XPath flavor of regexes (which is what is described on [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xpath.html)).

Though [backslashes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-8) are used in some regex engines as backreferences, python will first interpret `'\2'` in a string as an [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#escape-sequences), specifically for character code 2, the [start-of-text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#STX) control character. Either the backslash should be escaped (`'\\2'`), or the string should be made raw (`r'\2'`).

However, neither will address the ultimate issue. Firstly, not only are backreferences not stored across calls, they aren't stored between regexes; they are only valid within their own regex. Secondly, `lxml.etree._Element.set` isn't regex aware.

In this case, regexes aren't needed; the requirements are simple enough to implement without them. You can use [`lxml.etree._Element.get`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#get) to get the attribute value, then create the new value in Python.

```
for el in root_element.xpath('//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "XY")]/preceding-sibling::tok[1][starts-with(@xpos, "AB")]'):
    el.set('xpos', 'XX' + el.get('xpos')[2:])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, outis. Your solution works perfectly and, above all, your answer helped me understand why what I was trying didn't work. Learning XSLT seems to be the way to go in the sense that it is a full fledged programming language for XML and it provides a lot more power and flexibility but I guess you can go a long way with lxml.etree as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would use XSLT 1.0 with EXSLT support in Python:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:re="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="re"
    version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:param name="pattern">^(AB)([A-Z]+)</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tok[re:match(@xpos, '^(AB)([A-Z]+)')][following-sibling::tok[1][starts-with(@xpos, 'XY')]]/@xpos">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="re:replace(., $pattern, '', 'XX$2')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. In the end to get the job done outis suggestion was a lot easier to integrate in my workflow because it could simply replace some bits of code I already have and do what I needed. Knowing that XSLT has support in Python and that I can use regex is very useful.

Comment: What prevented me from trying out your stylesheet was that I need to do this to a few hundred documents. I'm a novice not only with XSLT but also with Python so I got stuck integrating your stylesheet in the code I had to go through all the XML files in a directory and apply a function with the 'for loop' that I had used in my question. So my question is, can one make a stylesheet into a function that is called from a Python for-loop?  :

def xml_change(root_element):                                                                         
      <xsl:stylesheet ...> .... </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Look at https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt and if you can't get it to work then ask a new question with details of what you have tried and how it failed. It doesn't make sense to try to answer your follow-up question in a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin! This is what I will do. I really see now I should invest some time  learning how to use XSLT with Python because it can provide solutions to many problems I'm likely to have working with XML docs.